# GCC warning: how to ignore -Wswitch-default on enum

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

The following code presents 3 cases where I want or don't want GCC warnings:

```
# include <iostream>

enum class MyEnum { FOO, BAR, BAZ };

int main()
{
    // Case 1
    int const a = 3;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1: std::cout << "you win !" << std::endl; break;
        case 3: std::cout << "oups... wrong !" << std::endl; break;
        // default is missing, I want a warning
    }

    // Case 2
    MyEnum const e = MyEnum::BAR;
    switch(e)
    {
        case MyEnum::FOO: std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; break;
        case MyEnum::BAZ: std::cout << "baz" << std::endl; break;
        // BAR is missing, I want a warning
    }

    // Case 3
    switch(e)
    {
        case MyEnum::FOO: std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; break;
        case MyEnum::BAR: std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; break;
        case MyEnum::BAZ: std::cout << "baz" << std::endl; break;
        // All the expected possibilities are all treated, I don't want a warning
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I can solve the case 2 without breaking case 3 by adding `-Wswitch-enum`.

I can solve the case 1 by adding `-Wswitch-default`, but it generates a warning for case 3.

I use gcc 8.5.0 (I can't upgrade).

**Is there a way to warn about missing `default:` but NOT for enum ?**

For the moment, my solution is to add a `default:assert(false);` after all the enum cases.

```
// Case 3
switch(e)
{
    case MyEnum::FOO: std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; break;
    case MyEnum::BAR: std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; break;
    case MyEnum::BAZ: std::cout << "baz" << std::endl; break;
    default: assert(false);
}
```

*Note: I don't want to just ignore warnings, because I turn all the warnings into errors.*

Comment: note that `e` can have other values. eg `3` is a valid value of an instance of `MyEnum`. However, compilers can warn for covering all enumerators which is what you want. I only refer to "All the possibilities are all treated" which isnt quite true. Assuming it would cover all possible values and ommitting the `default` can lead to subtle hard to trace bugs.

Comment: ... in other words, the branch in your last snippet isnt unreachable: https://godbolt.org/z/oe5c88oTn

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai okay... I discover that I can force to have `e = (MyEnum)10;`. It's a trap ! O_o Is there a warning for that ? ^.^'

I understand the reason.

Comment: `e = (MyEnum)10;` is a nasty C-style cast. Its easily caught by static analyzers and code review. But see my example, no nastyness is needed.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: `e = (MyEnum)10;` is undefined behavior, because it is outside the *bit-range* of the enum.  `e = (MyEnum)3;` would be defined behavior.  Or if the backing store of the enum were provided `enum class MyEnum : int { FOO, BAR, BAZ };`